# Use REGEXP_REPLACE to generate slug value with numbers

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, regexp-replace

I am using a function `REGEXP_REPLACE` within SQL to generate a `slug` value from `name` column

```
UPDATE tag
       SET slug = LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE(
                REGEXP_REPLACE('Team Building 2022', '^[^A-Za-z]+|[^A-Za-z]+$', '', 'g'),
                 '[^A-Za-z]+|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])', '-', 'g')
         );
```

But I get: `team-building`

Result I want is: `team-building-2022`

Is there a way to add numbers in this function? Thanks

Comment: Try 1) `^[^A-Za-z0-9]+|[^A-Za-z0-9]+$` and 2) `[^A-Za-z0-9]+|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=\D)(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=\D)`

Comment: It's working but it adds numbers with two -- . Like : team-building--2022 @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it with:

```
LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE(
      REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '^[^A-Za-z0-9]+|[^A-Za-z0-9]+$', '', 'g'),
         '[^A-Za-z0-9]+|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])', '-', 'g')
```

Answer (score -1):

Well you did not actually specify what result you want. but from the actual question and the reply to @WiktorStribiżew it appears like you are wanting `team-building-2022`. If that is correct then you just need a simple [replace() function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-string.html) (table 9.10) rather than a complicated regular expression. So just:

```
select lower(replace('Team Building 2022',' ', '-'));
```

If that is not the desired result then please post the exact result you want.

Comment: This will not work as on some columns it adds - on the end like: team-building-2022- @Belayer

Comment: True, but that is the type of condition you need in sample data. Further a data of  sample 1 is at best a poor sample.